# How to delimit a rails model with a constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, constraints

Is it possible (and how) to delimit an ActiveRecord model with "a where"? I.E. When I call `OrderCommunication.all` then the query would do something like `select * from ordcomm where type = 'order'`. I know it's kind of nasty but our database just can't be modified at all and we can't refactor. Basically I need to declare my model with a `where ordcomm = 'order'` so I don't do it in all my subsequent queries.

Comment: Damn, I think I just found my answer: `default_scope :conditions => ["type = ?", "order"]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `default scope` to get this done.

```
default_scope { where(type: 'order') }
```

Now, if you try `OrderCommunication.all`, you would only get the records with the `type` of `'order'`

If you instead want to fetch all the records, use `unscoped`

```
OrderCommunication.unscoped.all
```